# DeprecationWarning while using knn algorithm in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I am trying my hands on scikit-learn library. I imported the iris dataset, and tried to train knn algorithm to predict some outcomes. Here is the code:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

iris = datasets.load_iris()

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)

X = iris.data
y = iris.target

print X.shape
print y.shape

#training the model
knn.fit(X, y)

knn.predict([3, 4, 5, 2])
```

But I get the following error:

```
(150L, 4L)
(150L,)
DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)
```

I searched on google and found some workarounds. I tried using `X = X.reshape(-1, 1)` and also `X = X.reshape(1, -1)`, but then I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Analytics Practice/Social Media Analytics/Python Services/DataAnalysis/sk-learn-dir/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    knn.fit(X, y)
  File "C:\python-venv-test-2.7.10\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py", line 778, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, "csr", multi_output=True)
  File "C:\python-venv-test-2.7.10\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 520, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)
  File "C:\python-venv-test-2.7.10\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 176, in check_consistent_length
    "%s" % str(uniques))
ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [150 600]
```

What is the correct format of dimensions that the knn algorithm requires to be trained in scikit-learn?

Comment: How about upgrading your sklearn? Or you are already using the latest version?

Comment: The version that I am using is `0.18rc2`

Comment: It most likely doesn't like the 1-dim array that you pass into `predict`

Comment: I don't know what this KNN algorithm likes. Since if I try `y = y.reshape(-1, 1)`, it says `DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().`

Comment: And I don't know why people downvote such questions. Isn't this a valid question?

Comment: `X` and `y` are fine, but the data structure you pass into the `predict` fn - `knn.predict([3, 4, 5, 2])` - is not a 2d array. There are [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.predict) to find out what the KNN algorithm likes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @tttthomasssss for the help. Here is what I was doing wrong:

When I write `[3, 4, 5, 2]`, python interprets it as an array of dimensions 4X1, but when I write `[[3, 4, 5, 2]]`, python interprets it as 1X4 array. Since it is one data point having 4 different values for different features, I will have to input the predict model with `[[3, 4, 5, 2]]`. Here is the code which helped me to figure out the dimensions of both the arrays:

```
predict_array = [3, 4, 5, 2]
predict_array = np.asarray(predict_array)
print predict_array.shape

predict_array = [[3, 4, 5, 2]]
predict_array = np.asarray(predict_array)
print predict_array.shape
```

And here is the output:

```
(4L,)
(1L, 4L)
```